# Calculate the mean number of days between dates per group

Tags: r

My data are as follows:

```
year group date 
2019 A     2019-07-15
2019 A     2019-07-25
2019 A     2019-08-01
2019 B     2019-07-15
2019 B     2019-07-30
2020 A     2020-08-01
2020 A     2020-08-03
2020 B     2020-08-01
2020 B     2020-08-20
2020 B     2020-08-25
```

I would like to calculate the mean number of days between dates per year per group. I have tried the following code and receive the following error:

```
data_meandays <- data %>%
  group_by(year, group)%>% 
  mutate(Difference = date - lag(date)) %>%
  summarize(mean_time = mean(Difference, na.rm=TRUE))

Error in date - lag(date) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The class of my date column is Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because the `date` column is `character` and not `Date` class.  We need to convert to `Date` class before doing the difference

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
   group_by(year, group) %>% 
   mutate(Difference = date - lag(date)) %>% 
   summarize(mean_time = mean(Difference, na.rm=TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
   year group mean_time
  <int> <chr> <drtn>   
1  2019 A      8.5 days
2  2019 B     15.0 days
3  2020 A      2.0 days
4  2020 B     12.0 days
```

NOTE: the output from the difference between `date`s are `difftime` objects.  If we want to convert to `numeric` class, it would be `as.numeric` applied on the column

---

The OP's error can be reproduced if we don't convert to `Date` class

```
data %>%  
  group_by(year, group)%>%  
  mutate(Difference = date - lag(date)) %>%  
  summarize(mean_time = mean(Difference, na.rm=TRUE))
```

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `Difference = date - lag(date)`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: year = 2019, group = "A".
> Caused by error in `date - lag(date)`:
> ! non-numeric argument to binary operator
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), date = c("2019-07-15", "2019-07-25", 
"2019-08-01", "2019-07-15", "2019-07-30", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-03", 
"2020-08-01", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-25")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```